# Ajax.ActionLink navigates away

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have an Ajax.ActionLink that successfully calls my controller action but instead of updating the target with the return value, it navigates to a new page and shows the return value.

I have the unobtrusive ajax script in my view

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And these scripts are in my layout page

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is my action link:

```
<span id = "status">Account is Active</span> 
@Ajax.ActionLink("Deactivate", 
                "Deactivate", 
                "Lender", 
                new {id = Model.ID}, 
                new AjaxOptions {
                                HttpMethod = "GET",
                                Confirm = "Confirm Deactivation",
                                UpdateTargetId = "status"
                                })
```

My controller action:

```
public string Deactivate(int id) {
    var status = "Account is Active";
    ... // call method to deactivate account
    ... // set status = "Account is Inactive"
    return status;
}
```

The return value is correctly set. So why is the page navigating away instead of doing what Ajax is supposed to do, stay put?

Comment: Where's [`MicrosoftMvcAjax.js`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#ASPNET_MVC_Releases_on_the_CDN_10)?

Comment: The Microsoft files are no longer needed when using jQuery

Comment: @BradChristie just to verify I also included the MicrosoftMVCAjax file and it sgtarted working... I'm confused as to why everyone is saying the files are no longer needed and to use jquery instead if functionality is lost by removing them. TekPub MVC training recommends removing them as does Phil Haacks MVC 3 pro book...

Comment: It's my understanding that the AjaxHelper extension methods rely on that library. You can implement your own calls using jQuery (essentially picking up where the library left off) but natively it uses that file. I don't know enough about it personally, I just remember what little I did with Ajax and MVC I needed that file. Maybe grab the Debug version of that file and see what is actually being used?

Comment: Ok understood, thanks. If you want to add that to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` library to your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Notice how I included it in my answer which is the correct way. And **not** like this:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. Always use Url helpers.

Also make sure that unobtrusive ajax is enabled in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Make sure you have removed absolutely all traces of `Microsoft*.js` scripts. Those are completely obsolete and should not be used at all.

Comment: @CDSmith, no, it's not there. You haven't included it correctly. You have hardcoded the path. You must use an url helper. Look at my answer more carefully. Also make sure that you have removed all `Microsoft*.js` scripts from your page and that you have enabled unobtrusive AJAX in your web.config.

Comment: It might be hardcoded but it's there and is returned just fine in the browser, you're just being nitpicky. As I stated earlier, I had also thought that the Microsoft* files were un-necessary now and that the preferred method was jquery. So just verify, I removed the hardcoded script and used the URL Helper, i removed all the MS files and set the web.config as you stated. This caused my working solution WITH the MS files to stop working. So while you answer is doing all the "right" things, it doesn't work.

Comment: I managed to get your method to work. I had to start with a clean solution and work off of it. I must have had something wrong with my first solution. I appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include [`MicrosoftMvcAjax.js`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#ASPNET_MVC_Releases_on_the_CDN_10) with your list of scripts.

With regards to hearing it's no longer necessary, I'm not entirely sure how true that is, I've only found that when using the `AjaxHelper` extension methods, that file seems to make it all work out-of-the-box.

I did notice that MS's CDN doesn't show a MicrosoftMvcAjax.js file for MVC 4, so that may be the version that's switched to using purely jQuery, but I can't be entirely sure.

Comment: -1. `MicrosoftAjax*.js` is completely obsolete starting with ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: @Darin: I wouldn't even have posted an answer if it weren't for the comments to the original question. However, I'm glad you're in on the question now and are able to explain it.